# how to make one asynctask to start after the other one?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

what i have is two asynctask each one call a function to parse some data ... and i want the asynctask starts after asynctasknew finish how can i do this??? here is my code ..

```
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                try{
                    Intent newintent = getIntent();
                    mixlist=newintent.getStringArrayListExtra("listmix");
                    Log.e("listmix",mixlist+"");
                    for(int i=0;i<=mixlist.size();i++){
                        if(i==mixlist.size()){
                            Log.d("states","finished");
                             Item_Name="0";

                                Item_Price="0";

                                Item_Quantity="0";

                                Total_Price="0";

                                Customer_Name=name.getText().toString();
                                Log.e("customer_name",Customer_Name);
                                Customer_Number=mobile.getText().toString();
                                Customer_Address=addressnew.getText().toString();

                                //Call execute 

                                task.execute(); 
                        }

                        else{
                    Item_Name=mixlist.get(i);
                    i++;
                    Item_Price=mixlist.get(i);
                    i++;
                    Item_Quantity=mixlist.get(i);
                    i++;
                    Total_Price=mixlist.get(i);

                    Customer_Name="0";
                    Customer_Number="0";
                    Customer_Address="0";

    //              AsyncCallWSnew tasknew = new AsyncCallWSnew();
                    //Call execute 
                    AsyncCallWSnew tasknew = new AsyncCallWSnew();
                    tasknew.execute();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });


         } 

         private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    //Make Progress Bar invisible

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "order has been sent + item price", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intObj = new Intent(PersonalInfo.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intObj);
                    //Error status is false
                }


                //Make Progress Bar visible
                protected void onPreExecute() {

                }


                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     loginStatus = WebService.invokeLoginWS(Item_Name,Item_Price,Item_Quantity, Total_Price, Customer_Name,  

                   Customer_Number, Customer_Address,"InsertData");
                    return null;
                }


            }   

         private class AsyncCallWSnew extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    //Make Progress Bar invisible

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "order has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intObj = new Intent(PersonalInfo.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intObj);
                    //Error status is false
                }


                //Make Progress Bar visible
                protected void onPreExecute() {

                }


                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     loginStatus = WebService.invokeLoginWS(Item_Name,Item_Price,Item_Quantity, Total_Price, Customer_Name,  

                Customer_Number, Customer_Address,"InsertData");
                    return null;
                }


            }   
    }
```

when i make a debug my code works just fine .. but in normal run .. it doesn't can any help me?

Comment: You can call the 2nd `AsyncTask` in the `onPostExecute()` of the 1st `AsyncTask`.

Comment: You could use Facebooks Bolt Framework if you want to chain AsyncTasks https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android

Comment: i can't use it in post execute because the for loop maybe will run the asyntasknew more than one time according to the mixlist size and in the last calll for it m it will call the other asynctask .. so how can i do it?

Comment: @SpringBreaker - you should make your comment an answer, since it is THE answer

Comment: @user3628116 re: your for loop - simply test the status of your loop through the mixlist in onPostExecute, and if you have just processed your last entry then start your 2nd AsyncTask

Comment: it give me now an excpetion .. java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 8

Comment: @user3628116 - Think! size may be 8 but indexing starts at 0, you already apply that knowledge in your for loop test for < .size().

Comment: you are right !! it worked on post execute with some handling but can you put your comment as an answer so i can up vote it ?

Answer (score 3):

There are basically two possibilities:

- Simply start the next `AsyncTask` from `onPostExecute()` of the previous one
- Use [`AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) with [`SerialExecutor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR) and start all of them in a row.

Comment: i can't use it in post execute because the for loop maybe will run the asyntasknew more than one time according to the mixlist size and in the last call for it m it will call the other asynctask .. so how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use AsyncTask executeonExecutor method to start the async task. But it will require minimum API version 11. Kindly refer the following code.

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
     new YourFirstTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,params...);
     new YourSecondTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,params...);
  }else{
    new YourFirstTask().execute(params...);
    new YourSecondTask().execute(params...);
  }
```

For Lower version you can call directly. automatically system will process one by one.